# How to center itemize list vertically in tabular column

Tags: beamer, vertical-alignment, lists

Assume a beamer slide that is contains a `tabular`. One column of that tabular contains an `itemize` list. How do it vertically center the list within the tabular environment?

I have tested several options but none appear to work. See the MWE below:

```
\documentclass[t,smaller,compress,handout]{beamer}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\section{Aim: to vertically centralize the itemized text}
\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}{\insertsection}
    \begin{minipage}[t][0.95\textheight][t]{0.95\textwidth}
        \begin{table}[ht]
        %\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{c p{0.50\textwidth}}  % RESULTS IN ERROR
        \begin{tabular}{p{0.50\textwidth}p{0.50\textwidth}}
        %\vfill             % NO EFFECT
        %\vspace*{\fill}        % NO EFFECT
        \begin{itemize}
        \item Foo
        \item Bar
        \end{itemize}
        %\vspace*{\fill}
        %\vfill
        &
        \begin{figure}[center]
        \includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth, keepaspectratio]{example-image-1x1}
        \end{figure}
        \end{tabular}
        %\end{tabularx}
        \end{table}
    \end{minipage}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: Illustration of have and want]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have `table` inside a `minipage`, nor `figure` inside a `tabular`.

But you just need `columns`.

```
\documentclass[t,smaller,compress,handout]{beamer}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx}


\begin{document}

\section{Aim: to vertically centralize the itemized text}

\begin{frame}{\insertsection}

\begin{columns}[c]

\begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item Foo
    \item Bar
  \end{itemize}
\end{column}

\begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
 \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-1x1}
\end{column}

\end{columns}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You may add vertical space before `\begin{columns}` or remove the `t` option obtaining

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer, including the initial word of advice.